# Remotipart 406 Not Acceptable error in rails 3.1.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Previously my app was in rails 3.0 but when i updated to rails 3.1.1 , remotipart does not work.Instead of JS response it returns Html response.
I have a dashboard controller where action is demo_upload for uploading a file. 
I have tried all steps mentioned for remotipart at https://github.com/JangoSteve/remotipart but fails.
Form look like this 
{`<%= form_for(DemoUpload.new, :remote => true ,:url =>"/demo_upload") do |f| %>

```
<%= f.file_field :upload, :name => "upload" %>



 <div class="btnBlue">
<%= f.submit "Upload Photo", :id => "upload_photo" %>



 </div>
   <%= render :partial => "shared/loading_image"%>
<% end %>
```

`}

Do any one have solution for this please help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  I restarted my Webrick server, and the request was processed as JS.  Maybe that works for you too?

Answer (score 0):

Old but...

```
<%= form_for(DemoUpload.new, :remote => true ,:url =>"/demo_upload") do |f| %>
```

change to:

```
<%= form_for(DemoUpload.new,:html => {:id=>"Demo-upload", :'data-type' => :html,:remote => true,:multipart => true  }  ,:url =>"/demo_upload") do |f| %>
```

**Script:**

```
$("#Demo-upload").bind("ajax:complete", function(e, data, status, error){
    if (data.status === 200 || data.status === 201) {
            //success
    }else {
         // error
    }
})
```